# Boolean assignment in java

Tags: java, android

Can you explain this assignment? What does it mean?

```
boolean activityExists = testIntent.resolveActivity(pm) != null;
```

Comment: You couldn't have looked up boolean assignments in Java?

Comment: Are you asking about boolean evaluation or the `resolveActivity` method?

Comment: Perhaps it's clearer when written `boolean activityExists = (testIntent.resolveActivity(pm) != null);` ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It means to assign `true` if `testIntent.resolveActivity(pm)` does not return `null` otherwise assigns `false`.

Understandable long form of this would be

```
boolean activityExists;
if(testIntent.resolveActivity(pm) != null) {
    activityExists = true;
} else {
    activityExists = false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Checks whether `testIntent.resolveActivity(pm)` is null or not. If not null, activityExists value will be `true`, otherwise `false`.

Answer (score 0):

`activityExists` becomes `true` precisely if `testIntent.resolveActivity(pm)` is not `null`.

Answer (score 0):

It assigns `activityExists` to `true` if and only if the value returned by `testIntent.resolveActivity(pm)` is not `null`. Otherwise, `activityExists` is set to `false`.

Answer (score 0):

Basically it is saying that if that boolean is true, it means that there is some activity (the activity returned from the resolveActivity method is not null, it exists). For example, if resolveActivity returned null (nothing) it would be false, as it does == null, but if it returned a valid activity, nonnull, it would be true

Answer (score 0):

`testIntent.resolveAvtivity(pm)` will return something.  If it is not "null" then `activityExists = true`.  If it returns null (meaning it returned nothing), then `activityExists = false`.

Answer (score 0):

`testIntent.resolveActivity(pm) != null` is resolved to a boolean expression.  Whatever the method `resolveActivity(pm)` returns is compared with `null`.  If it is equal, then it returns false.  If it is not equal then it returns true.

The result of this comparison can then be assigned to a boolean value to be used later on in code.  You don't want to have to make the comparison each time unless you have to.